# Getting issue with Memory buffer on a running react native project

Tags: android, react-native, memory, command-line-interface, react-android

React native project was running absolutely fine. but after some time it suddenly started giving me an error on building the app. Here is the error report:

```
<-------------> 1% EXECUTING [1m 24s]
> Resolve files of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath
> Resolve files of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath > react-android-0.71.8-debug.aar > 4.6 MiB/189.9 MiB downloaded
> IDLE
> Resolve files of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath
> IDLE

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
MaxBufferError: stderr maxBuffer exceeded
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/Projects/xxx-react-native/node_modules/get-stream/index.js:41:19)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:283:11)
    at PassThrough.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)
    at node:internal/streams/transform:192:12
    at PassThrough._transform (node:internal/streams/passthrough:46:3)
    at PassThrough.Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:184:23)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Here the android development environment is set up but still getting this issue.

I commented these lines:

```
    // if (stream.getBufferedLength() > maxBuffer) {
            //  rejectPromise(new MaxBufferError());
            // }
```

and the issue is resolved for now.